# Implement callback function as interface in JNI and save reference in the function pointer

Tags: java, c++, callback, java-native-interface, function-pointers

So basically I have such struct in the C++ side:

```
typedef int(*callback)(int, int);
typedef struct InfoCallback {
    int a;
    int b;
    callback call;
} InfoCallback_t;
```

And I would very much enjoy filling this struct on the Java side with JNI (or even SWIG but this is much harder?). I am aware that I should be using `interface` on Java side as a callback feature but I can not wrap my head around it.

On the Java side I would like to have a function

```
private native void fillAndPrintStructCallback(int a, int b, Callback callback);
```

and I assume that my interface should possibly look somewhat like

```
public interface Callback {
    int onCallback(int a, int b);
}
```

where the JNI function body should look at least like this

```
  InfoCallback_t *info = new InfoCallback_t;
  info->a = a;
  info->b = b;
  // can't come up how can I store the reference here to the passed implementation of the Callback
  info->call = ???;
  delete info;
```

I know how to pass around primitives but I can not think of a way how could I store a reference on the C++ side to the Java callback. How could I achieve it?

Comment: You could create a global reference to the `Callback` instance (with `NewGlobalRef`) and store that (a `jobject`) in the struct. When time comes to invoke the callback you use `GetObjectClass` and `GetMethodID` to obtain the ID of the `onCallback` method, and invoke it using `CallIntMethod`. Then you delete the global reference. If it's a recurring callback rather than a one-shot callback you'd have to modify this strategy a bit and come up with some way of signalling when it's safe to delete the reference.

Comment: JNA has Java callbacks with function pointers.